# Kendo Grid - Custom Editor function not being called

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

I have the following html and two functions, used to add a custom editor to a grid with a checkbox. The checkbox is displayed correctly when first bringing up the grid using the checkBoxTemplate function, but when I try to update, the checkBoxEditor function is not called, and thus I don't get a checkbox, but rather the string "checkBoxEditor". What am I doing wrong?

```
        <div id="dependencyGrid" data-role="grid"
            data-scrollable="true"
            data-editable="inline"
            data-sortable="true"
            data-toolbar="['create']"
            data-bind="source: dependencies"
            data-columns="[                  
                { field: 'ActiveFlag', title: 'Active', width: 30, editor: 'checkBoxEditor', template: '#=checkBoxTemplate(data.ActiveFlag)#' }
            ]">
        </div>

    checkBoxEditor = function (container, options) {
        if (options.model.ActiveFlag == 1)
            $('<input type="checkbox" checked=checked  class="chkbx activeflag" ></input> ').appendTo(container);

        else
            $('<input type="checkbox"  class="chkbx activeflag" ></input> ').appendTo(container);

    };

    checkBoxTemplate = function (input) {
        if (input == 1 || input == true) {
            return '<input type=checkbox checked=checked class=chkbx   disabled=disabled ></input>';
        }
            return '<input type=checkbox class=chkbx   disabled=disabled ></input>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct, basic way to do this. I just didn't have my checkBoxEditor function defined where it could be accessed by the html... So, it you want to set up a custom editor for a checkbox, this should work for ya.